# Using pivot model data as a relationship to another model in Laravel 4's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a pivot table for a many to many relationship which includes a third index parameter for another model. I would like to be able to use Eloquent to access this model.

In my application, I have a `User` who can have many `Subjects` and many `Semesters`. When a user has a `Subject`, it needs to belong to a given `Semester` as well. I have a `users`, `subjects` and `semesters` table, as well as a `subject_user` table (which has `user_id`, `subject_id` and `semester_id`).

When I retrieve the `User`'s subjects, I would also like to be able to get the `Session` the `Subject` has been connected to through the pivot table.

```
class User
{
    public function subjects()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Subject')->withPivot('session_id');
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is as follows, and have the `Session` model available to me.

```
$user->subjects()->pivot->semester;
```

Is such a thing possible, or will this require an extension to Eloquent?

Comment: Ever come up with a solution? Have a similar problem.

Comment: My solution was to use a UserSubject model which had it's own relationships defined. I did make a feature request for this in Eloquent but it was turned down. I think a join model is a fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this by creating a class that extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`. Though this approach also requires adding some code to the two models that own this pivot so that they use the new Pivot when needed.

This link discusses the implementation of the Custom Pivot Model:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2093#issuecomment-39154456

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class SubjectUser extends Pivot {
   // add your relationships back to User and Subject
    public function session() {
         // your relation to session here
    }
}

class Subject extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        if ($parent instanceof User) {
            return new SubjectUser($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        }
        return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {
        if ($parent instanceof Subject) {
            return new SubjectUser($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
        }
        return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
}
```

Now you will have access to that pivot's relationship that have been defined.

```
$user->subjects->first()->pivot->session->...
```

**Note:** You will not be interacting with this class directly. It is created instead of the default Pivot when the pivot is needed between those 2 models.

Laravel Doc Reference: [Working with Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) has a short passage about Defining a Custom Pivot Model.