# How to modify a relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, pivot-table, relationship

My app has 2 main modules which are `Foo` and `Bar`. It also has 3 types of role: `admin`, `manager` & `staff`.

Each user is assigned to a supervisor, so that every supervisor will have some subordinates assigned to him/her.

For example, staff1 is supervised by manager1 whom is also supervised by admin1.

The current practice for this relationship is implemented in both modules. Therefore each supervisor is in charge for the subordinates in the matter of their `Foo` and `Bar`.

**User.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
class User {
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password','supervisor_id'];
    protected $appends = ['role'];
    public function getRoleAttribute(){
        return $this->roles[0];
    }
    public function getNameAttribute($value){
        return Str::title($value);
    }
    public function parent(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserStructure', 'user_id');
    }
    public function scopeSupervisor($query){
        return $query->where('id', $this->supervisor_id)->first();
    }
    public function foo(){
        return $this->hasMany(Foo::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
    public function bar(){
        return $this->hasMany(Bar::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**UserStructure.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class UserStructure extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'parent_id'];
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Role.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Role extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'role');
    }
}
```

**RoleAndPermission.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
class RolesAndPermissionsSeeder extends Seeder{
    public function run(){
        $roles = ['admin','manager','staff'];
        app()[\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class]->forgetCachedPermissions();
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            Role::updateOrCreate(['name' => $role]);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserSeeder.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\User;
use App\UserStructure;
class UserSeeder extends Seeder{
    public function run(){
        $items = [
            ['role'=> 'admin',
             'name'=> 'admin',
             'email'=> 'admin@myapp.com',
             'password'=> 'password',
             'supervisor_id'=> 1],
            ['role'=> 'manager',
             'name'=> 'manager',
             'email'=> 'manager@myapp.com',
             'password'=> 'password',
             'supervisor_id'=> 1],
            ['role'=> 'staff',
             'name'=> 'staff',
             'email'=> 'staff@myapp.com',
             'password'=> 'password',
             'supervisor_id'=> 2],
        ];
        foreach($items as $data) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                'supervisor_id' => $data['supervisor_id'],
            ]);
            $user->assignRole($data['role']);
        }
        $userStructure = [
            ['parent_id'=> 0, 'user_id'=> 1],
            ['parent_id'=> 1, 'user_id'=> 2],
            ['parent_id'=> 2, 'user_id'=> 3]
        ];
        UserStructure::insert($userStructure);        
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I modify this relationship accordingly so that any supervisor [`admin`/ `manager`] will be assigned to the subordinate [`manager`/ `staff`] of one module only?

(*E.g:
In `Foo` module, **staff1** is supervised by **manager1**.
While in `Bar` module, he will be supervised by **manager2**.*)

Comment: Do you have any updates to this question? It is a really interesting question, thus I up-voted it in order to get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you can add one column to the **Role** model (like type), and then assign roles to users with a condition