# Laravel pivot relationship on relationship (Eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

In Laravel, is it possible to put a relationship within a relationship?

Basically, I already have a relationship set up, but I then need another relationship for that relationship (if that makes sense).

My two models:

- Store
- Supplier

My relationship model for Store and Supplier:

- SupplierStore
- store_id
- supplier_id

As you can see, I have many **stores** and **suppliers**, each of whom can relate to each other through the **SupplierStore** table.

This works perfectly.

**My problem is** that for each relationship (of Store and Supplier) there can be
many Delivery Days.

My HasMany relationship:

```
DeliveryDay
supplier_store_id
day
```

I thought if I go into the **SupplierStore** model and add:

```
public function days()
{
 return $this->hasMany('App\DeliveryDay');
}
```

Would work, but there is no way I can seem to access this data through eloquent?

I was hoping to do something like this:

$supplier = Supplier::find($id);
$supplier->store->pivot->days

The pivot (SupplierStore) would hold the relationship of that specific relation and I could grab the days.

Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do to achieve this? Your time is much appreciated. After googling for hours, my head hurts so much. :)

Comment: is SupplierStore already a model?

Comment: hasManyThrough? - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367440/using-pivot-model-data-as-a-relationship-to-another-model-in-laravel-4s-eloquen

Comment: Yeah, SupplierStore is a model. It's the model which is used for the BelongsToMany relationship between Supplier and Store. That model itself also has a relationship of HasMany for DeliveryDays.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I need to define a relationship inside the pivot model for making easier queries. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could access each day like this:

```
public function getDays($id)
{
 $supplier = Supllier::find($id);

 foreach($supplier->stores() as $store)
 {
   foreach($store->days() as $day)
   {
    echo $day->day;
   }
 }
}
```

Or get all days

```
$supplier->stores->days;
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, I appreciate your help. But I don't think what you've suggested is the solution. What I want to access the relation within the relation. Eg $supplier->store->pivot->days

Comment: Oh my bad, so you want to acess the days using your supplier model?

Comment: Yeah man, it seems like it's just not possible. Which sucks! I if I dd($supplier->stores->pivot) - there is a relations line but it is a blank array, it doesn't have the days() relation I added into the relation. Really weird.

Comment: ```$supplier->stores``` could you dd  this and see if is returning your SupplierModel? if does you can acess the days using a foreach loop

Comment: So if I do something like this. $supplier->stores->first(), it will show me the first relation. I can then do $supplier->stores->first()->pivot which will show me the actual relationship model. Inside the "pivot" I can't see days, even if I try and foreach say $supplier->stores->pivot->days it thinks it is a column on my SupplierStore model not a relationship. If I do $supplier->stores->pivot->days() it just says function doesn't exist.